# how to stop image download instead of image display in aws s3 using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have upload an image using node.js in AWS S3 and that have successfully uploaded on AWS S3 bucket, but I try to view the image instead of download. I cant view that downloded file. I have used following code to upload an image on AWS S3:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var config = require('../../server/config');
AWS.config.update({ 
 accessKeyId: config.aws.accessKeyId,
 secretAccessKey: config.aws.secretAccessKey,
 region: config.aws.region
});
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var Busboy = require('busboy');
var busboyBodyParser = require('busboy-body-parser');
app.use(busboyBodyParser());
app.post('/upload', function(req,res){
    var directory = req.body.directory; 
    console.log(req.files.file);   
    var image = req.files.file.name;
    var contenttype = req.files.file.mimetype;
    if(req.body.directory) {
        var file = directory+'/'+image;
    } else {
        var file = image;
    }
    var data = req.files.file.data;
    var keys = {
        Bucket: req.body.bucket,
        Key: file,
        Body: data,
        ACL: 'public-read',
        contentType: contenttype
    };
    s3.upload(keys, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
           res.send({
                isError:true,
                status:400,
                message:"File Not Uplaod",
                data:err
           });
        } else {
            var data = {
                Location: result.Location,
                key:result.key,
                Bucket:result.Bucket
            };
            res.send({
                isError:false,
                status:200,
                message:"File Uplaod",
                data:data
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was stuck with this as well, but the following works:

```
let params = {
  ACL: 'public-read',
  Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
  Body: fs.createReadStream(req.file.path),
  ContentType: req.file.mimetype,
  Key: `avatar/${req.file.originalname}`
};
```

***req.file.mimetype*** is what fixed it, which is basically the same as `ContentType: image/jpeg` but it identifies the extension of the file the user has uploaded as opposed to having to hardcode `image/jpeg` or `image/png`

I hope your issue is fixed though.

Answer (score 1):

I have find that answer :

used ContentType:'image/jpeg' or ContentType: 'your variable' in keys to upload image in aws s3